# Hasta cuando los votos de castigo y la nefasta forma de Moderación/CM no mueven un dedo

Tags: discusión

Entiendo que el sitio tiene normas, pero que pasa cuando alguien abusa de las normas, las ignora o las usa de papel higiénico...

Si simplemente es lo mismo de siempre... una pregunta o respuesta correcta con las normas del sitio y comienzan a salir uno que otros votos negativos sin ningún sentido, esto lo he reportado ya anteriormente y he aquí cuando inicia el principal problema.

Ni la moderación del sitio ni los CM se pronuncian al respecto, se tiran la bola entre ellos diciendo que no pueden hacer nada y que el otro es el que tiene que intervenir y el otro dice que no puede hacer nada porque los votos son anónimos.

Las 5 personas que dicen ser la comunidad piden pruebas, que obviamente no existen por la conducta o la funcionalidad que tiene el sitio.

No se abre una investigación o hacen algo evidente al respecto... simplemente se excusan diciendo que no harán nada al respecto o comienzan a preguntar (los mod) que quiere uno (la persona afectada) que hagan... es como si fuesen elegidos sin saber cuáles son los compromisos que voluntariamente aceptaron.

Por qué nadie se preocupa de la calidad de los usuarios o si le dan un uso correcto a las herramientas.

Ojo que no estoy hablando del sistema de Votos de Cierre, hablo del sistema de Voto de Reputación. Porque ya vendrá algún genio sacando alguna cortina de humo y desviando el enfoque de este post.

Entonces me queda la duda sobre:

**¿Que se Necesita para que los administradores de este sitio (CM o quien este arriba) le pongan un ojo al sistema de votos que se usa como castigo?**

***Pruebas:*** este es mi dia a dia ... votos negativos ramdon de diferentes usuarios en diferentes preguntas que no son detectadas por el sistema de correccion de votos... Cuanto odio y toxicidad silenciosa existe en este sitio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Citemos lo que dice la ayuda:***

> **¿Qué es votar negativo?** La emisión de votos negativos, también conocida como "votar en contra", es la forma en la que la comunidad
> indica qué preguntas y respuestas son menos útiles.
>
> **¿Cuándo debo votar negativo?** Utiliza tu voto negativo cada vez que encuentres una pregunta o respuesta atrozmente descuidada, poco
> rigurosa, sin ningún esfuerzo empleado, o que es clara, pero quizás
> peligrosamente incorrecta.
>
> Tienes un número limitado de votos por día y además votar negativo en
> una respuesta te cuesta un poco de reputación. Utiliza estos votos de
> manera sabia.

Le pregunto a la comunidad, si ya hay un uso establecido en la ayuda y se sabe que usuarios osciosos e irresponsables le dan mal uso a la herramienta, por que se sigue padrinando el uso indevido y no se acepta que es un problema de la comunidad ... o es que son tambien participes ...

Comment: Hola, te sugiero no desesperar, 1) recuerda lo que se ha comentado anteriormente, los votos son anónimos, el usuario decide su voto positivo o negativo, si dejara de ser anónimo seguramente habría mucha fricción entre los usuarios 2) Debes [respetar las reglas del sitio, y principalmente a los usuarios del mismo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct). Como moderadores tratamos de ser tolerantes, en SO si realizaras una publicación como esta seguramente serías suspendido durante mucho tiempo.

Comment: _Llover votos negativos_ Si hablamos de tu ultima pregunta respuesta, tienes un total de 1 (uno) votos negativos. Debo recordarte además que en el sitio no están aceptadas las palabras malsonantes, deberías editar tu pregunta para eliminarlas. Estás en tu derecho de dar tu opinión, pero las faltas de respeto no son toleradas en el sitio.

Comment: Creo que te preocupas demasiado. Los llamados a la reflexión no funcionan. Yo lo que hice fue despreocuparme, a lo sumo hablar del tema pacificamente, y no pensar tanto en las normas, si no en ayudar a otros siempre que sienta que la comunidad recibirá bien o neutro mis respuestas. Deja que la comunidad se caiga sola.

Comment: @DanteS. _los llamados a la reflexión no funcionan_ que te hace pensar eso? A lo mejor si se ha reflexionado y se ha llegado a una conclusión diferente a la que esperabas. No es posible?

Comment: @Pikoh Me corrigo, no tienen el efecto deseado o suficiente.

Comment: @DanteS. de verdad que no es por discutir, pero...efecto deseado o suficiente...por quién? o para quien? Si es el efecto deseado por ti, es posible. Si es el efecto deseado por al comunidad..tal vez haya tenido el efecto deseado y suficiente para la mayoria :)

Comment: Por algunos de nosotros. No hemos visto cambios fuertes en el sitio.

Comment: Si no hay cambios fuertes, es posible que la mayoría no quiera esos cambios. Yo me resisto a creerme poseedor de la verdad absoluta e intentar cambiar la vision de los demas para adaptarla a la mia y tiendo a creer mas en la democracia. Pero esa es mi forma de actuar, es algo personal. Un saludo

Comment: quienes son la mayoria de los que hablas, los 5 gatos o más que van a votar aquí negativamente o los Ciento de Usuario qué pasan por el sitio y se largan a los 3 días por la mala recepción o los usuarios viejos que ya tiraron la toalla y nisiquiera entran a meta o al chat... por que ya saben los desechos qué encontrarán y la ideología obtusa qué prevalece....

Comment: **Los comentarios han sido [movidos al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149532/discussion-on-question-by-arcanisgk507-hasta-cuando-los-votos-de-castigo-y-la-ne); por favor, no continuar la discusión aquí.** Antes de publicar un comentario bajo este, por favor revisa los [propósitos de los comentarios](/help/privileges/comment). Los comentarios que no pidan clarificaciones o sugieran mejoras normalmente deben ser publicados como una [respuesta](/help/how-to-answer), o en el [chat]. Los comentarios que continúen la discusión podrán ser eliminados.

Comment: Comparado con las demás comunidades en internet, esta es mucho más tolerante. Eso, sin embargo, no quita que el voto negativo sea usado parcialmente como dislike. Y eso pasa también en meta51. Eso, sumado a que, probablemente, fuiste ganando haters. Espero algún dia, la red de stack exchange sea aun más tolerante.

Comment: @DanteS. creo que no hay que romantizar los errores/problemas comparandolos con lo grave que pueden estar otros sitios... es como decir que un politico roba pero tambien hace ... o justificar que hay peores politicos ... las normas del sitio no tiene terminos medios... por hay dicen que estan para cumplirce las normas ... entonces como se justifica tal flexibilidad ... no tiene sentido ... lamentablemente si hay haters como dices el mismo sistema los patrocina dandole herramientas anonimas para fastidiar a otros ...

Comment: No romantizé ni justifiqué, lo que quize decir es, que si bien el sitio es más tolerante, estaría bueno que lo fuera aún más

Comment: @DanteS. _Comparado con las demás comunidades en internet_ .... jajajajajaja

Comment: El sistema otorga el privilegio del voto negativo con 125 de reputación. Lamentablemente, más que eso no se puede hacer :( Sobre tu nuevo comentario, leiste lo que dije después de la frase citada? Y mi explicación?

Comment: vuelves a romantizar las cosas ... que una persona a los 18 años pueda conducir un auto para movilizarce no le da el derecho de atropellar a las personas ... lo mismo pasa con el sistema de votos ... que te den el privilegio de emitirlo no quiere decir que le puedas darle un mal uso  ... recuerda que la herramienta de votos en meta tiene un uso distinto al del sitio principal en español ...

Comment: No lo hice, no mencioné que tuviera derecho a votar así. Por que interpretas de ese modo? Tomando el ejemplo del auto: te hacen un examen de conducción, lo pasás, e igualmente pasás semaforos en rojo y resulta que es un comportamiento tan arraigado y aceptado que nadie puede multarte. No hay mucho que hacer, aunque estemos en desacuerdo. Cuando fuí a meta51 a preguntar por que no aceptaban nuevos sitios en español, me pusieron negativos. No tiene sentido. Finalmente, volviste a ignorar lo de que no romanticé.

Comment: Oh, revisé tus respuestas con negativo. Y no vi normas rotas por tus respuestas, así que te doy la razón que con algún mal votante chocaste. Tampoco explicaron el ban a nuestro compañero. Así que si, hay algo de corrupción

Comment: por lo menos aceptas ese _algo de corupcion..._ el cual no deberias tampoco de justificar ... en mi pais si te pasas una luz roja hay una camara que te toma foto y te multa ... al igual que si vaz a exceso de velocidad ... entonces: si vives en un pais donde la cultura es cumplir las leyes cuando te vigilan o cumplir solo el 80% de ellas estas mal eso no justifica que el sitio deba ser asi ... no estoy de acuerdo con ningun tipo de corrupcion ...

Answer (score 3):

Arcanis entiendo tu frustacion, sobre todo cuando inviertes tiempo en hacer una respuesta y te dan un voto negativo, o el propio usuario que hizo la pregunta la elimina despues(esto duele mas). Las dos cosas me han pasado, y si molesta bastante.
Respecto a los votos negativos considero que a veces hay un comportamiento no etico, te explico: Una vez que un usuario ha alcanzado cierto nivel de reputacion, no considero etico que si se equivoca en su respuesta se le de un voto negativo sin decirle en que se equivoco, yo veo eso como una maldad y una falta de respeto, lo correcto seria por respeto a su puntuacion y a sus conocimientos sobre todo, avisarle y decirle que se equivoco en algo(generalmente un usuario de alta puntuacion se equivoca en cosas triviales, pero se equivoca por que es un ser humano no un robot), pero todo recae en la etica, a mi me ha pasado a veces he tenido razon y otras no(yo siempre echo la pelea y el que se moleste tiene doble trabajo). Tampoco entiendo porque cuando das una respuesta a una pregunta de "poca calidad"(digase el usuario no puso codigo o no demostro conocimiento) te castigan con votos negativos, lo importante es que la respuesta sea correcta, y nadie tiene que meterse con ella, algunos diran ¨son las reglas del sitio¨ y a esos le respondo ¨pues cambienlas¨ porque no tienen ningun sentido(pero es mi opinion, mi punto de vista), hay gente que no saben votar ni en sus paises ni en stackoverflow, y tambien hay seres humanos que no le importa nada.

PD: Me encanta stackoverflow, creo que tiene muchas mas cosas buenas que malas, y a pesar de que alguna que otra vez he tenido algun encontronazo con algun moderador, sepan que los respeto y los valoro.

Comment: No creo que este sitio tenga reglas estrictas, es el sesgo que hay por aquí. Sin embargo, compartimos la misma opinión sobre los votos :). Tengo una frase interesante sobre la gente que no le importa nada: si ver el mundo arder les conviene, entonces encenderán un fosforo y lo tirarán en un bosque.

Comment: el caso es que no es nisiquiera el hecho de no poner codigo... una pregunta legitima con una respuesta legitima ... que sigan las normas del sitio ... igual recibira votos de castigo cuando veen quien hizo el post, ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/606950/c%c3%b3mo-definir-rutas-paths-en-proyectos-php-tanto-para-aplicaciones-web-como-de

Comment: no hay ningun motivo razonable. simplemente un usuario troll, se pasas por donde tu saves el correcto uso de la herramienta .... y los dueños de la herramienta simplemente no hacen nada ... y las personas que nos representan como comunidad tampoco hacen nada ... cuando te acercas a preguntarles ... te dicen tratan de #"$&"$& por auto-valorar tu tiempo y tus puntos de reputacion que otro viene joder.

Comment: lo peor es que este tipo de actividad troll, pasa desapercibida por el bot, por que uno no responde cada 5 segundos una respuesta... y no tiene donde meterte mas votos negativos.

Comment: y volvemos a caer en ese circulo vicioso de que cada X tiempo te meten votos negativos y nadie hace nada al respecto ... y te sueltan la cortina de humo preguntando que quieres que se haga ...