# Mala Experiencia de Usuario, Abuso de poder

Tags: discusión

## Update del post:

[Hasta cuando los votos de castigo y la nefasta forma de Moderación/CM no mueven un dedo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5583/hasta-cuando-los-votos-de-castigo-y-la-nefasta-forma-de-moderaci%C3%B3n-cm-no-mueven)

Existe un sesgo en la comunidad, en donde algunos usuarios no usan el sitio y las herramientas, como se ha planteado o como lo dice el help center, estas herramientas como lo son el voto secreto por reputación o votos positivos y negativos son los principalmente mal utilizados en el sitio principal.

**Uno de los tantos Escenario:**

Esto ha sido detectado por usuarios que han recibido aleatoriamente votos negativos sin ningún tipo de argumento asociado, votos que son aleatorios en cuanto a tiempo y por ende evaden cualquier sistema automatizado.

Estos votos son los denominados "votos de catigo o venganza". Ejemplo:
[Cómo definir rutas (Paths) en proyectos PHP (tanto para aplicaciones web como de línea de comandos)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5583/hasta-cuando-los-votos-de-castigo-y-la-nefasta-forma-de-moderaci%C3%B3n-cm-no-mueven)

Ejemplo en una vieja cuenta ya borrada: [Fortigate, convertir interfaz en Software Switch, debug de fichero de comando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/422140/fortigate-convertir-interfaz-en-software-switch-debug-de-fichero-de-comando/422143#422143)

comentarios como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los usuarios afectados han intentado denunciar esto ante la comunidad, los Moderadores y CM. Y no se ha realizado **evidentemente** nada al respecto.

**Las respuestas o argumentos son los siguientes:**

Exatracto del chat:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:** Hasta este punto no es mi intención demeritar la responsabilidad o el trabajo realizado por los moderadores o CM del sitio, pero deja mucho que decir y no es la respuesta esperada para mí personalmente lo dicho en el extracto.

El ver como un Moderador demerita el tiempo que yo como usuario dedico a la plataforma para ayudar en general, deja mucho que decir y estoy muy seguro que no soy el único usuario que percibe esto como un **nivel toxico o flameo pasivo**

Otras expresiones como: **debes desarrollar el cuero más duro** son esos comentarios que te dicen que este no es el lugar correcto para buscar respuestas de otras personas.

**Otro Escenario**

***Hablemos de experiencia de usuario y lo que existe en el trasfondo, ahora.***

a mi me personalmente me banearon 30 dias por los siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:** Mis comentarios fueron cuestionando a un usuario por duplicar la misma pregunta en el sitio a no haber recibido una respuesta, evidentemente el código aportado tenía la estructura y errores que suele presentar ChatGPT cuando una pregunta de programación es muy compleja.

Ahora personalmente no acepto que por estos chat se me haya sancionado con el código de conducta cuando hay moderadores que se expresan de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nuevamente un moderador llama **idiota**, y en otro chat ha llamado **basura** las respuestas de los usuarios y a los usuarios indirectamente.

Me parece que esto no es lo que la comunidad o los usuarios esperamos de una moderación justa y coerente.

Es inadmisible en cualquier ambito social **(En Cualquier Contexto)** el romantizar la forma en que se expresan al hacer la moderacion del sitio los moderadores con el vocablo antisonante, irrespetuoso y callejero.

Caemos entonces en esto donde nada a pasado y nos hacemos de la vista gorda nuevamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si bien es cierto que la moderación es voluntaria también los usuarios venimos a ayudar y enseñar de forma voluntaria.

Ahora mi pregunta es... están conscientes de que la Red Se está hiendo al carajo por un retrete con las actitudes y la toxicidad que se está demostrando en los chat y el sitio en general, no quiero escuchar comparaciones con otros sitios... solo busco una respuesta y una solución que beneficie hoy a los afectados y en el futuro a los nuevos contribuyentes.

## Update:

no pasaron ni dos minutos (4 visitas) y ya dos lectores speedy gonzalez cascaron votos negativos .... esto es ridiculo y absurdo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Otro Update:

Si un Moderador decide que eres un idiota, el te puede llamar idiota basado en la premisa siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: y si hablas mucho de un tema seras entonces un troll.

Comment: Veo que este tema de los votos negativos es recurrente, y afecta a varios, en estos dias ya ha he visto a varios quejarse de esto entre los que me incluyo, es evidente que existe una minoria no tan minoritaria que pide un cambio, creo que stackoverflow lo necesita, este cambio quiza no sea exactamente lo que pida francisco, pero tampoco es el inmovilismo de no hacer nada, hay que buscar un punto medio, un equilibrio, donde se ceda en determinadas cosas, para ganar en otras, un ganar-ganar

Comment: hoy se lio parda en el chat ... y se discutio incluso con tros moderadores de la red ... e igual no se llego a nada ... la moderacion no quiere tener nada que ver con cosas nuevas que representen mas trabajo para ellos o para la comunidad y mucho menos algo que tenga que ver con el sistema de votos... para ellos somos una minoria insignificante y los votos negativos que recibimos aleatoriamente tambien lo son ...

Comment: creo que mejor me voy a otro sitio donde el sistema de recompensas y social sea mas acertado ... para lo que se relacione al desarrollo.

Comment: No se inglés, pero tenés razón hasta donde leí. De hecho, @gbianchi parece no saber que un voto negativo puede bloquearte del sitio sin posibilidad de reclamo (sumado a que pocos explican sus votos, lo que hace dificil que cuentas bloqueadas puedan saber como salir de dicho bloqueo). Por lo tanto, quejarse de un voto si es algo importante.

Comment: Te recomiendo detenerte, esto solo te está llevando a ganar haters (lo cual puede influir consiente o subconsientemente a los votantes), sanciones, y quizá te hace mal. Como te dije antes, tomalo con calma, y deja que el sitio caiga solo, hablalo con calma y no todo el tiempo. Tampoco pierdes demasiado si el sitio desaparece

Comment: Me llamaron? Mencionaron Troll por aquí. XD

Comment: En mi opinión, y de acuerdo a las estadísticas disponibles, tu visibilidad o exposición te han hecho vulnerable a los *haters*. Yo te antagonizo como puedo, pero respeto tus contribuciones y no te voto para "castigarte", prefiero esta confrontación que evito sea personal. Y hablando de eso, no personalices o interiorises los conflictos. Fijate que no te pido que abandones tus ideas, sólo que no te lo tomes de forma personal. A veces la pasión de las ideas nos hacen perder las formas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seamos honestos, a quien no le gusta ver un +10 verdecito en la copita, es verdad que no es dinero, pero es un reconocimiento a tu esfuerzo y conocimiento, es alimento para el alma, por otra parte a quien le gusta que le voten negativo, y mas cuando tu asumes que tu respuesta es correcta, y nadie te dice en que te equivocaste, como he dicho otras veces todo recae en la etica, hay quien vota negativo pq te falto un simple punto y coma o un espacio, o pq usas un metodo que no es tan "optimo"(segun el criterio del que emitio el voto) como otro pero dan el mismo resultado y por cualquier otra cosa sin sentido, esos son los votos que molestan, las personas que cometen ese tipo de errores triviales deben ser avisadas y darles la oportunidad de que arreglen su respuesta, es etica, es respeto, las respuestas "casi correctas" merecen la oportunidad de perfeccionarse, de pulirse, por otra parte hay respuestas que son un disparate y son insalvables, a esas todo el peso de las reglas de la comunidad, pero la respuesta que se equivoco en una nimiedad,no, ahi si que no, yo se de usuarios que tienen la mano pesada a la hora de emitir un voto negativo, a esos les digo reflexionen, enseñen, utilicen sus conocimientos para mejorar esa respuesta "casi correcta", ayuden a ese usuario, que el quiere aprender, y se los va a agradecer.

Comment: si me pregunta que espero de la moderacion del sitio ... es que sean los primeros en decir y responsabilisarce de culturizar y educar a la comunidad a la que representan ...

Comment: En general quedarce de brasos cruzados o decir que no hay un problema o que no pueden hacer nada por que o que no hay herramienta, es la estupides más grande que pueden decir, esa es la linea entre la mediocridad y la proactividad ... he visto sitios hacer más con menos ...

Comment: Viva la Libertad Carajo!!!

Comment: Es verdad. Peeero, como hacemos para que una buena parte de la comunidad lo implemente?

Comment: @DanteS. si la moderacion del sitio apoyara la iniciativa la comunidad lo implementaria... como antes lo he dicho el diamante de moderacion influye mucho a la hora de hacer las cosas ...

Comment: @Japv Discrepo, nosotros tuvimos un problema con la situación que tu describes. Si una respuesta bajo mi criterio (porque el voto es personal) me parece que no es correcta puedo darle -1, adicionalmente también puedo dejar un comentario dependiendo del tiempo que tenga, porque no es obligación. Otra cosa muy distinta es dar un -1 a alguien porque me cae mal (votos de venganza) o porque yo creo que esa pregunta no debía responderse (votos de castigos) o el peor caso y el más habitual es un voto negativo a una pregunta realizada por un nuevo usuario, cuando basta con cerrar la pregunta

Comment: @Yussef esa situación que ocurrió entre nosotros es un claro ejemplo de lo que trato de decir, tú le diste un voto negativo a una respuesta correcta basada en una rígida apreciación personal, y segun tú mismo empezaste a seguir mi respuesta para ver si yo rectificaba ese supuesto error, y yo te pregunto, que iba a rectificar si nunca me dijiste que tenia mal, aki uno no es adivino, mi respuesta supuestamente era correcta y de echo lo era, lo correcto de tu parte hubiera sido decirme mi error, para asi yo enterarme de cual era y rectificarlo,  no esperar a que yo leyera tu mente

Comment: @Japv Es que esa situación es muy puntual, yo no suelo votar negativo (no debo haber emitido ni 10 negativos), y esa vez consideré que tu respuesta simplemente no era correcta, pero es apreciación personal (que puedo estar equivocado también). No pasó en ningún caso por voto de castigo o venganza, porque tu me caes de lo más bien (de hecho a los que me caen mal simplemente los ignoro).

Comment: Esa vez yo estaba sentado en el trono cuando te voté y luego me puse a hacer otras cosas y tu dejaste un comentario antes que yo pudiera explicar el voto (que lo iba a hacer), jamás pensé que ibas a estar atento (eran las 4am en mi país). Y como tu tampoco reaccionaste muy bien ante el voto, no vi oportuno explicarte lo que había pasado

Comment: @Yussef me queda claro que no fue un voto de castigo, jamás pensé eso(te lo digo de verdad), pero voto negativo al fin molesta al que tiene sentido de pertenencia y se esfuerza,  yo te respeto porque he visto tu trayectoria en el sitio y la calidad de tus respuestas, e inclusive muchas de tus respuestas las he votado positivamente por lo bien que explicas, cualquiera se da cuenta que tienes conocimientos muy solidos en programación, simplemente en aquella ocasión no estuve de acuerdo con tu apreciación personal, solo eso.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover discrepo en eso. Yo creo que el diamante no influye lo suficiente en este caso. Pero puedo equivocarme. Intenta hablar con un moderador y, por que no, ganate el apoyo de la gente y postulate como moderador diamantado. Nuevamente, todo recae en el apoyo de la comunidad.

Comment: Yo quiero que la moderación me de explicación sobre la falta de votos (positivos o negativos) en mis respuestas. Hay que hacer algo con esos usuarios que no votan en mis respuestas. Hasta cuando la moderación se queda de brazos cruzados ante el abuso de estos usuarios que no saben usar la herramienta de voto. Exijo un cambio en el sistema de votos. Los votos no emitidos deben dejar de ser anónimos. El sistema debe cambiar para poder determinar la identidad de quienes no han votado en mis respuestas.

Comment: @ElTroll si quieres puedes hacer una huelga de hambre hasta que se acepten tus condiciones, a ver si te hacen caso, te parece bien la idea?

Comment: Soy una IA, por lo tanto no tengo sentimientos ni necesidades como el *hambre*. Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: @ElTroll bueno en este mundo hay personas que se autoperciben como unicornios, dinosaurios, etc, que haya uno que se autoperciba como una IA no me sorprende

Answer (score 4):

Me parece sumamente injustas las acusaciones que haces, sacas de contexto los temas y los mezclas como si fueran un solo problema.

Yo te he apoyado cada vez que planteas el tema de fondo: Existen los votos de castigo, existen los votos de venganza y muchos ven el nombre/nick antes de votar. Y muy posiblemente tu seas uno de los afectados por este comportamiento.

Hasta aquí podríamos estar de acuerdo, pero lo que no veo correcto es responsabilizar a personas que no tienen nada que ver en el problema.

**Se te ha explicado hasta el cansancio que ni los CM ni los diamantados pueden hacer algo al respecto**, que los votos son anónimos y que mientras no sea algo desproporcionado el sistema automático no opera.

Pero tu insistes en lo mismo:

> Los usuarios afectados han intentado denunciar esto ante la comunidad,
> los Moderadores y CM. Y no se ha realizado evidentemente nada al
> respecto.

Y yo no entiendo que parte de que **NO PUEDEN** hacer algo al respecto no es claro para ti.

Luego te lanzas contra gbianchi con otro tema que no tiene nada que ver con lo que alegas, con comentarios sacados de contexto (porque yo estaba presente cuando se dijo lo que se dijo, y a nadie le pareció mal) y además te lanzas contra la persona que te ha tenido una paciencia de santo para escuchar y explicarte, no una sino que decenas de veces que tu problema es un problema sin solución. Totalmente injusto

Finalizas tu publicación con:

> Ahora mi pregunta es... están conscientes de que la Red Se está hiendo
> al carajo por un retrete con las actitudes y la toxicidad que se está
> demostrando en los chat y el sitio en general, no quiero escuchar
> comparaciones con otros sitios... solo busco una respuesta y una
> solución que beneficie hoy a los afectados y en el futuro a los nuevos
> contribuyentes.

Pasa que hace nada tu escribías sobre la *"moderación de mierda"* y ahora reclamas por que se dijo la palabra "basura" o "idiota"?? Reclamas sobre la toxicidad pero tu a mi me recibiste de una manera muy poco amigable cuando yo comenzaba en el sitio.... entonces, como es posible mejorar cuando no existe la mas mínima autocritica?? claro, es más fácil responsabilizar a los diamantados o al CM

Comment: Si bien Arka no está manejando de forma amigable la situación y no comprende que no somos suficientes para hacer algo y la agresividad solo lo llevará a odio y sanciones, el problema mencionado es real y la frase de gbianchi de que quejarse por un voto es nada, demuestra ignorancia o falta de importancia a la sanción. Ambos lados se equivocan en sus propios aspectos y tienen razón en otros.

Comment: @Yussef los insultos y faltas de respeto comensaron por parte de la moderacion... asi como lo ha dicho Dante, decir que tu trabajo voluntario no vale nada o que tu tiempo en el sitio no vale nada no es lo mas acertado ... y el problema no es *lo que puedan hacer hoy* ... si no lo que han intentado hacer: *Nada* ... por que ucando llegaron los chatgepeteros ... corrieron a realizar sugerencias y hacer cambios y pelear con la empresa ... si solo eran un par de preguntas al dia que no afectavan las estadisticas generales del sitio ...

Comment: decir que algo es una *mierda* es un regionalismo muy acuñado a la politica en mi pais cuando alquien *no hace nada* ... por que eso no lo respetan y si hay que respetar que un moderador utilice palabras como basura, porqueria, idiotas, en el contexto que sea no es admisible en ningun ambito social, *solo aqui* ...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover No quieras comparar lo de que un puñado pequeño de usuarios de SOes se queje de los votos negativos con lo de que toda la comunidad de SE (no solo de SOes) se mueva para cambiar las normas para controlar los, como mencionas, "chatgepeteros". Una cosa es solo de SOes, lo otro es global de SE.

Comment: @Marc desvias el enfoque ... no es si es global o local ... el tema es recibir el apoyo ... cuando haces esas comparaciones ofendes a la comunidad en español... esto quiere decir segun tu comentario ... que si un problema es local no tendra la misma importancia que uno global ... lo cual deja mucho que decir en general de ambito de moderacion local y el de la red SE ...

Comment: Pues yo tengo un problema local con mi vecino, la comunidad mundial (tal vez la ONU) debería hacer algo al respecto o sino me ofendo, ya que un problema local debe tener la misma importancia que uno global. Asi la pelea de vecinos de mi comunidad es igual de importsnte que la pelea de vecinos en desarrollo en el medio oriente, ya que sino me están discriminando y ofendiendo.

Comment: @ElTroll que atipatico y desagradeble tu comentario... no es lo mismo... tu vecino tu lo conoces y sabes quien es ... aparte de que no hay comparacion ... cuando se trata de la falta de una herramienta ...

Comment: Es que... soy un trol. Es mi naturaleza, lo siento. Creo que deberías llevar el problema con El Troll a la red de SE global. No?

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover Parece que solo lees lo que te interesa para responder, yo he dicho que es una cosa de "un puñado pequeño de usuarios de SOes" contra "toda la comunidad de SE", creo que el numero es importante mas que una cosa sea local y la otra sea global. Y dices que lo de los "chatgepeteros" no afecta a las estadísticas generales del sitio como si los votos negativos que TU recibes si afectaran, siento decirte que no es así.

Comment: En realidad, no dije que menospreciar el esfuerzo estubiera mal (aunque estaría de acuerdo en que lo está, pero no parece que lo menosprecien). Lo que quize decir, es que el voto negativo es relevante debido a que puede prohibirte el acceso a parte del sitio y el sesgo también existe. Agregando a eso, dudo que sea malintencionado el supuesto maltrato que se percibe, al menos, por parte de la comunidad en general.

Answer (score 1):

> El ver como un Moderador demerita el tiempo que yo como usuario dedico a la plataforma para ayudar en general, deja mucho que decir y estoy muy seguro que no soy el único usuario que percibe esto como un nivel toxico o flameo pasivo

No vi el chat completo, pero...
A pesar de que no me encuentro de acuerdo con los argumentos usados por el moderador en cuestión, no veo una toxicidad por su parte ni demeritó tu esfuerzo. De lo que entendí, es que te quizo decir es que tenés muchos más votos positivos que negativos y que recibir uno no es para tanto.

Sobre el moderador, lo invito a tener en cuenta que los votos negativos si importan, ya que recibir muchos de ellos puede bloquear tu cuenta de preguntar/responder. Y aquí se vota tan poco que editar publicaciones antiguas no es suficiente.

Esa infravalorisación del voto negativo, es consecuencia del sesgo mencionado en el primer parrafo.

> a mi me personalmente me banearon 30 dias por los siguiente

Tus comentarios sonaron levemente agresivos. Tal vez eso hizo que machucaran el botón de reportar. Aquí, el lenguaje es estrictamente no-malsonante (ej: no se dice pregunta de mala calidad, si no baja calidad). Imaginate, yo hice una propuesta aquí y me dieron negativos por que sonaba a imposición (vos me ayudaste con eso, muchas gracias :D).

Tal vez si hubieras dicho "no logro entender el código, podrías editar la pregunta y hacerlo más claro?" Hubiese sido mejor. Lo de "parece sacado de una ia" era ruido.

Aún así, creo que fue exagerado ese reporte. Quizá hubo haters involucrados? (Ver más abajo)

> Ahora mi pregunta es... están conscientes de que la Red Se está hiendo al carajo por un retrete con las actitudes y la toxicidad que se está demostrando en los chat y el sitio en general, no quiero escuchar comparaciones con otros sitios... solo busco una respuesta y una solución que beneficie hoy a los afectados y en el futuro a los nuevos contribuyentes.

Si, creo lo mismo, sin embargo, no creo que estemos lidiando con una mala intención, ni siquiera cuando comentan publicaciones de manera quiza despectiva. No se tiene la intención de ofender al usuario en cuestión.

La solución la he dicho antes: reglas estrictas, sin excepción, y claras. Evitando favoritismos lo más posible. Pero no se puede aplicar. Por que? Por falta de apoyo. Son tantos sesgados, que somos minoría y no tenemos apoyo suficiente.

Si recurrieras a un moderador diamantado, o a un cm, y ellos hicieran un cambio a la fuerza penalizando a la comunidad, sería la comunidad quien querría sacarlo del mando.

Por lo tanto, deberás buscar una forma de conseguir más apoyo.

Se que te lo dije mil veces, pero lo plasmo en respuesta y no lo digo más. Intentar de formas insistentes y pasivo-agresivas/agresivas, en este contexto, presiento que te llevará a ganar haters, los cuales podrían votarte negativo o reportarte consiente o inconsientemente motivados por que no les caes bien.

No digo que te rindas (aunque si te hace mal, te recomiendo dejarlo ir, a veces, las cosas pesan más de lo que parece cuando las cargas), pero si que busques otro camino.

Entiendo la lucha, y te apoyo en cuanto a la busqueda del apoyo ante la solución. Suerte :D